Gcode coordinate transformations relative to rotation axis
I've tagged this as CNC, though I recognize that it is likely more of a math issue (which also explains why I am having trouble with it!).
I'm using a 4-axis CNC that contains two rotary axes. It is effectively a milling lathe, though my axes definitions aren't "standard". Rotary axis A rotates the work piece and effectively replaces Y translations, and the tool itself sits on the B axis.

What I would like to be able achieve is to take some Cartesian gcode (XYZ coordinate with origin at their local center) and transform those to cut a dimensionally-accurate shape at any given radius and B rotation angle (perpendicular to any tangent plane to a surface)
In the orientation of the image above, with B = 0°, this transformation is a "wrapping" on a cylinder with radius r, so: A(degrees)=Y/r * pi/180. However, this transformation would have to change as the B angle changes.
When B = +/-90°, the transformation requires polar coordinates:

X and Z will ultimately swap (based on X= Xcos(-90) + Zsin(-90), and Z = Zcos(-90) - Xsin(-90). At a radius r from the rotation axis, X will be converted to polar radius (taking into account that local coordinate system vs global) with 
And the A angle will be: 
Where I am really stuck is how to deal with any of the B angle ranges in between. It is obvious that that as B approaches 0° it will be more of a "wrap" and as it goes toward 90° it will become more polar, but I haven't been able to think through a way to take into account how much of each would be needed in a case like this: 
Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Happy to clarify anything that doesn't make sense.

You would have far less problems if you would express yourself with 4*4 affine matrices. And model the chains as matrix multiplications.

Matrix math ftw. You can express the 4x4 as a 3x4 data buffer if you want to save space for the constant 0001 the in the data buffer at supports translation.

I appreciate the input. I can certainly see that using a rotation matrix can approach at least part of the problem. This certainly makes it easy to get the transformation around the B (Y) axis. However, I still have problems visualizing how to get out the appropriate rotation around the A axis, based on this B axis rotation.
